# Sum pattern across array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm having trouble finding the proper way to do something I think should be trivial using numpy. I have an array (1000x1000) and I want to calculate the sum of a specific pattern across the array.

For example:

If I have this array and want to calculate the sum of a two-cell-right diagonal I would expect `[7,12,11,8,12,6,11,7]` (a total of 8 sums).

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This operation is called a 2-dimensional [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.signal import convolve2d
>>> kernel = np.eye(2, dtype=int)
>>> a = np.array([[5,3,7,1,2],[3,2,9,4,7],[8,9,4,2,3]])
>>> convolve2d(a, kernel, mode='valid')
array([[ 7, 12, 11,  8],
       [12,  6, 11,  7]])
```

Should you want to generalize it to arbitrary dimensions, there is also [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html) available. It will also work for this 2d case, but does not offer the `mode='valid'` convenience.

Comment: Follow up: How about calculating the sum of two cells aligned to the right? I.e. for my example I would get [8, 10, 8, 3, 5, 11, 13, 11, 17, 13, 6, 5] (12 values). I'm not allowed to use a 1d array as 'kernel', and when I try np.array([1,1]).reshape(1,2) get something completely wrong :P

Comment: Do same thing, with this kernel:  `np.array([[1,1]])`. Actually it's the same kernel as `np.array([1,1]).reshape(1,2)`, which also seems to give correct result to me.

Comment: Thank you, wim. I apparently have a poor understanding of numpy arrays :P All good now (Y)

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [[5,3,7,1,2],[3,2,9,4,7],[8,9,4,2,3]]
[q+l[w+1][t+1] for w,i in enumerate(l[:-1]) for t,q in enumerate(i[:-1])]
```

then you can avoid using numpy :) and the output is

```
[7,12,11,8,12,6,11,7]
```

Comment: This task is a scientific computing task, therefore using numpy is appropriated IMO. The accepted solution is more flexible than this one (should you want to use another kernel), and faster on big problems (for the 1000 x 1000 problem, ~ 15 times slower on my machine)

Comment: sometimes simplicity is also a big factor to remember, how ever if you get it to be 15 times slower then, i'll give your right. It's prop. not worth it :)